# access to the row of a dataframe using the conditions and values for unnamed columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
params = pd.DataFrame({ 'dE'    :   {'3.0':20.0, '4.0':15.0, '-4.0':15.0},
                                    'Gg'    :   {'3.0':80.0, '4.0':55.0, '-4.0':55.0},
                                    'gn2'    :   {'3.0':50.0, '4.0':10.0, '-4.0':10.0}  })
```

The data inside:

```
        dE    Gg   gn2
3.0   20.0  80.0  50.0
4.0   15.0  55.0  10.0
-4.0  15.0  55.0  10.0
```

How to access the row of a dataframe where the first unnamed column has value 4.0?
How actually create a subset using the unnamed column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That unnamed column named index of row.

How to get row value of index 4.0 is `params.loc['4.0']`

Answer (score 1):

In pandas version 1.5.2 the first "column" that you think is unnamed actually is the index.

Then to locate row use: `params.loc['4.0']`